# Erase and reset my arduino

Tags: arduino

By some reason, I wrote the code below and upload it into my arduino, and obviously, I forget a delay function in loop method.

So, every time I pin the arduino into my computer, the simulated keyboard is always input something and can not stop.

I want to erase or reset my arduino, but how can I work it?

Type of board is Leonardo Micro Mini.

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Keyboard.print("Hello.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that it's difficult for you to upload, for instance, the BareMinimum example because of the Arduino printing "Hello." on your keyboard.
 Is this right? If so, I see three possible solutions.

1. unplug the arduino, load the BareMinimum example, push the "Load" button and, when the compilation starts, plug the arduino back. It should start printing "Hello" but, in the end, it should load the sketch on the leonardo.
2. keep the reset button pressed; hit the load button in the IDE, then, as soon as the IDE says "loading" (after the compilation) release the switch. An alternative is to just press the reset button at the right moment, but I think that keeping it pressed is less annoying
3. use a programmer (or even another arduino - google for Arduino as ISP for more infos) to load the bootloader again on the leonardo

Bye

Comment: I tried the first two methods, click the 'Load' button, and plug the arduino back at the time 'loading' appears, but it doesn't work.The IDE is block up in 'loading' word, I think maybe the usb hub is filled with keyboard command stream, consequently the IDE can not get status of arduino.

Comment: Even if you keep the "reset" button on the arduino pressed?then I'm afraid the best way is to flash the bootloader again..

Comment: Micro Mini board has no "reset" button, I can upload codes directly.

Comment: Well, you have the RST pin, so you just have to short-circuit it with GND to keep it in the reset state